# attribute writer display password

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm just starting to learn ruby on rails and using 
http://ruby-for-beginners.rubymonstas.org/writing_classes/attribute_writers.html

The article doesn't explain how to display the password

Here is my code.

```
class Person
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def name
    @name
  end

  def password=(pass)
    @password = pass
  end

  def greet(other)
    puts "Hi " + other.name
    puts "Your password is " + #(how do i call password here?)
  end

end

  person = Person.new("Lee")
  person.password = ("super secret")
  person.greet(person)
  p person
```

I'm not understanding attribute writers at this point.
Can anyone help me?
Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

While you have already set class variable `@password = pass`

You are able to call it as `@password`, remember if password wasn't set, it will give an error.

```
  def greet(other)
    puts "Hi " + other.name
    puts "Your password is #{@password}"
  end

person = Person.new("Lee")
person.greet(person) #will give an error
person.password = "pass"
person.greet(person) #will print the password
```

Comment: Perfect. That's exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks so much!